# sharp corner for circle(draw on canvas) in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, paint

i am drawing  chart using canvas.

Bitmap image;

image=  //here i get bitmap which i want to draw on canvas

Canvas canvas=new Canvas(image);

// i have draw circle as follow

canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);

but circle corner is not sharp:

ii is showing something like this:

[image]

how to i make circle outer radius sharp..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

When you initialise your paint, set these properties:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

See the Android documentation for what each one does;

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html

Comment: hi simon thanks for reply..,but i have we have already set this.

Answer (score 1):

set the anti alias

`paint.setAntiAlias(true);`

Comment: are you using an image from the drawable folder? if so, the image might be to large or to small for the screen to handle.

Comment: no i am not using image from drawable, we have bitmap(empty) like this:BitmapbmImage= Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);      
        canGlobalCanvas=new Canvas(bmImage);

Answer (score 1):

**let's say:**

```
cx = 108.0F;
cy = 108.0F;
radius = 88.0F;
canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
```

Example:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
     p.setAntiAlias(true);
     p.setFilterBitmap(true);
     p.setDither(true);
     p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     p.setStrokeWidth(3.75F);
     p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
     Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(216, 216, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp1);
     canvas.drawCircle(108.0F, 108.0F, 88.0F, p); // since the bitmap size is 216
         //then, the starting (x) and the end (y) points must begin from 
         //the center to be a nice circle, that's why I used 108 as 108*2 = 216.
         //and the 88 is the radius of the desired circle
```

Comment: care to explain? This was flagged by someone as low-quality.